# Populate a Listview from a String-Array

Tags: android, android-listview, populate, arrays

I have a ListView where I'm filling it in through `String tutorialTitle1 = getResources().getString(R.string.tutorial1_title);`, but for the purpose and functionality of my app I have no choice but to use a `String-Array`

I've never worked with the `String-Array` and I'd like some help to implement every item in my ListView. At the moment I'm doing it this way

```
public class tutorialActivity extends Activity{
    String[] values; 
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tutorial);
        registerClickCallBack();
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.tutorialList);

        String tutorialTitle1 = getResources().getString(R.string.tutorial1_title);
        String tutorialTitle2 = getResources().getString(R.string.tutorial2_title);
        String tutorialTitle3 = getResources().getString(R.string.tutorial3_title);
        String tutorialTitle4 = getResources().getString(R.string.tutorial4_title);
        String tutorialTitle5 = getResources().getString(R.string.tutorial5_title);
        String tutorialTitle6 = getResources().getString(R.string.tutorial6_title);
        String tutorialTitle7 = getResources().getString(R.string.tutorial7_title);
        String tutorialTitle8 = getResources().getString(R.string.tutorial8_title);
        String tutorialTitle9 = getResources().getString(R.string.tutorial9_title);
        String tutorialTitle10 = getResources().getString(R.string.tutorial10_title);
        String tutorialTitle11 = getResources().getString(R.string.tutorial11_title);
        String tutorialTitle12 = getResources().getString(R.string.tutorial12_title);
        String tutorialTitle13 = getResources().getString(R.string.tutorial13_title);
        String tutorialTitle14 = getResources().getString(R.string.tutorial14_title);

        values= new String[] { tutorialTitle1, tutorialTitle2, tutorialTitle3, tutorialTitle4, tutorialTitle5, tutorialTitle6, tutorialTitle7, tutorialTitle8, tutorialTitle9, tutorialTitle10, tutorialTitle11, tutorialTitle12, tutorialTitle13, tutorialTitle14};

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);


    }

    private void registerClickCallBack() {
        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.tutorialList);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View viewClicked,int position, long id) {

                Intent i = new Intent(viewClicked.getContext(), tutorialContentActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("tutorialNumber", position);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

But now `R.string.tutorial1_title` doesn't exist anymore because I've put it like

```
<string-array name="tutorialTitle">
    <item>Tutorial Content</item>
    <item>Tutorial Content</item>
    <item>Tutorial Content</item>
    <item>Tutorial Content</item>
    <item>Tutorial Content</item>
    <item>Tutorial Content</item>
    <item>Tutorial Content</item>
    <item>Tutorial Content</item>
    <item>Tutorial Content</item>
</string-array>
```

So basically how can I populate my Listview with all the items I have in my `<string-array name="tutorialTitle">`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Call `getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tutorialTitle)` to retrieve the `String[]` associated with your `string-array` resource.

Comment: Just to keep in mind, you can set `android:entries="@array/tutorialTitle"` too.