# How to generate a items in a listview from an array?

Tags: java, android, xml

Let's say I have a listview with the id 'stringList', and an array called 'stringListContents'. How would I populate the listview from the array with index 0 being first obviously, and the list ending at array.getLength?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Populate a Listview from a String-Array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17034316/populate-a-listview-from-a-string-array)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ArrayAdapter in android to create simple listview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19079400/arrayadapter-in-android-to-create-simple-listview)

Answer (score 3):

If I undestand your question correcly, you could use something like this:

```
public class MyListActivity extends ListActivity {
    ...
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, stringListContents);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, stringListContents);
    stringList.setAdapter(adapter);
```