# How to dereference <string-array> android resource into Java Array object

Tags: android, arrays

Given a

```
<string-arrayname="stringArray">
<item>item1</item> 
<item> item2</item>
<item>item_N</item>
</string-array>
```

resource in Android XML, how do you get all the  of the string-array into a Java primitive String [ ] stringArray;

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17034334/115145

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, fix this: `<string-array name="stringArray">` note the space before "name"
Then,
`String[] values = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.stringArray);`